# How to change 2 types of file extensions on one button click in c#?

Tags: c#, file, format

I would like to change more file extensions at the same time, for example change all .txt files to .txt.NO and .jpg.NO to .jpg

My code looks like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
    {
        File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(".txt", ".txt.NO"));
        File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(".jpg.NO", ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

I get and error when I try to do 2 changes at once. When I was using only the first `File.Move` line alone my program was working.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You're trying to move _the same file_ twice at the same time. You should construct an if/else statement that checks if the file is .txt, or is .jpg, and then behaves accordingly.

Comment: After you do the first `File.Move`, the file is (possibly) moved to a different location. The second call then can't find the file at the location stated by `f.FullName`, causing your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you rename the file in the first line, the second would fail because the file no longer has that name.

You need a condition based on the file extension.

```
foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
{
   if(f.FullName.EndsWith(".txt"))
      File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(".txt", ".txt.NO"));
   else if(f.FullName.EndsWith(".jpg.NO"))
      File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(".jpg.NO", ".jpg"));
}
```

Comment: Just an idea: you could use `f.Extension` instead of `f.FullName.EndsWith` to make it a bit "cleaner"

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Just a note :) .. `f.Extension` will not return `.jpg.No`.. It would return `.No` only.

Comment: at the end of:else(f.FullName.EndsWith(".jpg.NO"))
I get " ; expected" when my code looks like yours
Any solution? :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are moving/renaming the same file two times and in your second `Move` the property `f.FullName` is still the one with the `.txt` extension but this file does not exist anymore because you moved it already.

You should use a condition to check if it's a textfile or an image.

Something like this for example

```
foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
{
    if (f.FullName.EndsWith(".txt"))
    {
        File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(".txt", ".txt.NO"));
    }
    else if (f.FullName.EndsWith(".jpg.NO"))
    {
        File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(".jpg.NO", ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work due to i have one .txt file nad one .jpg.NO file and your method changes only the .txt file to .txt.NO but it does do nothing to the .jpg.NO